# Bokeh unable to display Berlin in Germany map

Tags: python, gis, bokeh, geojson, geopandas

I'm using Bokeh and Geopandas to plot an interactive map of Germany. Germany has total 16 states but the plot shows only 15. It does not display the map of Berlin, which is the capital city (Berlin is also a state). I'm using the shapefile as an input to plot the map. I have tried different shapefiles and looked for different solutions but I'm unable to find the root of the problem. Please have a look at the code and the output.

`

```
import pandas as pd
# Import geopandas package
import geopandas as gpd
# Read in shapefile and examine data
germany = gpd.read_file('Igismap/Germany_Polygon.shp')
pop_states = germany
vargeojson = pop_states.to_json()
```

```
import json
from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import (ColumnDataSource, 
                          GeoJSONDataSource, HoverTool,
                          LinearColorMapper)
from bokeh.layouts import column, row, widgetbox
from bokeh.plotting import figure
output_notebook()
# Input GeoJSON source that contains features for plotting
geosource = GeoJSONDataSource(geojson =  vargeojson)
```

```
tools = "pan, wheel_zoom, box_zoom, reset"
p = figure(title = 'All states of Germany', 
           plot_height = 600 ,
           plot_width = 600, 
           toolbar_location = 'right',
           tools = tools)
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.ygrid.grid_line_color = None
# Add patch renderer to figure.
states = p.patches('xs','ys', source = geosource,
                   line_color = "grey", 
                   line_width = 0.25, 
                   fill_alpha = 1)
# Create hover tool
p.add_tools(HoverTool(renderers = [states],
                      tooltips = [('Lander','@name')]))
show(p)
```

`
[Click here to see the output of above code....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jspt6.png) and
[Click here to see the desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rsd3.png)

Comment: My sense is that Berlin is there, just under another polygon. Bokeh may have trouble to plot a hole in that polygon in this case.

Comment: I don't understand where in this code you're actually displaying Berlin. Is it supposed to be a point or a polygon? I wouldn't expect an individual city to be in a collection of state polygons

Comment: @martinfleis I guess you are right. When I inspect the plot in browser, it does show this warning in console: "Bokeh does not support Polygons with holes in, only exterior ring used." Any idea on how to cope with this or any work around? I found these two links (https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/glyphs/multi_polygons.html#bokeh.models.glyphs.MultiPolygons) and (https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html#polygon-with-holes) in Bokeh documentation related to the warning message, but they were not very helpful for me.

Comment: @PaulH In the third line of code, I'm reading a shapefile "Igismap/Germany_Polygon.shp". I'm plotting polygons using this file and Berlin should be automatically plotted as the other 15 states. Please check the images that I provided, it might help to get a clear picture.